# Errors occurring on running C program

Tags: c, linux, structure

I wrote a C program on Linux. When I compile the program, no errors occur, but when I run it, I receive a number of errors. My program is,

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct a{
 char *name;
 int id;
 char *department;
 int num;
} ab;

int main()
{
 ab array[2]={{"Saud",137,"Electronics",500},{"Ebad",111,"Telecom",570}};
 printf("First student data:\n%s\t%d\t%s\t%d",array[0].name,array[0].id,
     array[0].department,array[0].num);

 //ab swap(&array[]);
}
```

Errors are:

```
./newproject: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
./newproject: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
./newproject: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x8): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
./newproject:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here
./newproject: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
./newproject: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtend.o:(.tm_clone_table+0x0): multiple definition of `__TMC_END__'
./newproject:(.data+0x10): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: error in ./newproject(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Your code compiles fine here. How exactly do ou compile this code ? Are you sure the code you show here is the code you are actually compiling ?

Comment: need to share your makefile or the way you compile it. Nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: if your main is int, need to return some int. Possibly you are compiling with a wrong compiler.

Comment: Don't know if it will help but... Have you read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237490/error-in-makefile-multiple-definition-of-start

Comment: on terminal first i write, gcc -o newproject newproject.c

Comment: then to run it i wrote, gcc ./newproject

Comment: @SaudFarooqui please edit your question and make that clear __there__.

Comment: I found nothing of my point in the link given by you above, he asked about some makefile problem but i think my problem is looking same but it is different

Comment: i have mentioned everything in the question my program.... my errors, i only want to know about how to fix these errors

Comment: @SaudFarooqui  no, in your question you didn't write how you compile the program and how you run it.

Comment: on terminal, to compile i wrote the command gcc -o newproject newproject.c

Comment: @SaudFarooqui yes I understgood now, but next time you ask a question here, put __all__ relevant information into the question.

Comment: saud@saud-VirtualBox:~$ gcc -o newproject newproject.c
saud@saud-VirtualBox:~$ gcc ./newproject
I am compiling by the above commands

Answer (score 1):

To compile you need to write this:

```
gcc -o newproject newproject.c
```

this creates a file named `newproject` which you can run by writing this:

```
./newproject
```

It doesn't make any sense to write `gcc ./newproject` to *run* your program.

Comment: Thanks to pick the mistake

Comment: @SaudFarooqui - Please consider to accept the question if it solved your problem. That will help us all to see that the problem has been solved.